# Do NPN and PNP phototransistor switch complementarily?

Tags: phototransistor

I am trying to understand whether there is a difference in the switching characteristics of NPN and PNP phototransistors.

My understanding is:
NPN: current flows when light is incident, no current without light

PNP Option 1: current flows when light is incident, no current flows without light

PNP Option 2: current flown when NO light is incident, no current flows with light

Is option 1 or option 2 correct?

Many thanks.

Comment: read the datasheet before you ask

Comment: They act similarly- light = conducting. If you are not using the base you can flip E and C on one and approximate the other. PNP phototransistors are scarce as hen's teeth.

Answer (score 1):

The physics are the same for NPN or PNP.

Incident light creates hole-electron pairs in the Base-Emitter PN junction. These are driven by the external field to provide a base current that biases the transistor. This base current will be amplified by the beta of the transistor to generate a collector-emitter current.

The only difference is in the direction of the current, i.e., how to externally bias the transistors.

Answer (score 0):

In a bipolar junction transistor, current flows between collector and emitter when there's carriers in the base that can flow across the reverse-biased collector-base junction.

In the usual presentation, those carriers are injected into the base via the emitter and the base connection, because the base-emitter junction has been forward-biased by increasing \$V_{be}\$ above zero (in an NPN) or decreasing it below zero (in a PNP).  However, those carriers can also be left over when you suddenly turn off voltage to the base, which is why transistors have a reverse recovery time.  They can also be created by photons smacking into electrons in the base region and shoving them out of position, creating electron-hole pairs.

To a first approximation, a phototransistor is just a regular transistor that forgot to close the bedroom curtains.  In a dark room, with no voltage on its base, it acts like a regular transistor with no voltage on its base -- it doesn't conduct.  When light shines on its base, it generates carriers, because photons (see above).  As a consequence current starts to flow from collector to emitter (and it develops its own \$V_{be}\$, as a side effect).